# A low quality post question

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I'm in the review part and came cross this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283290/using-the-bellman-ford-algorithm-whats-the-proper-way-of-traversing-each-edge) by [paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421195/paulsm4).

I skipped it because 1) I'm new to this part of the review process, 2) If I were to choose "Recommend Deletion" for " This is commentary on another post, not an answer", I felt that he provided more than enough information to be a comment only.

So for future reference, what would this be classified as? "Recommend Deletion" or "Looks OK"

Comment: It's from 2011. The rules were possibly more lax at that point, but it hasn't gotten a single upvote since 2011. I would vote to delete as it should be a comment. Even the poster agrees that it is not an answer in their post.